# Simple Bash Script: Change names of files to mimic directories

Tags: bash, substitution

I have 312 directories labeled,

```
Ion_0001- Ion_0312.
```

In each directory I have a file light.out.  I'd like to change the file names in each directory to, for example:

```
Ion_0001.out
```

I believe I also need to substitute the / so that my output DOESNT look this this:

```
Ion_0001/.out
```

Can any one help me out with a simple script??

This is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in  */
do
cd $dir

for filename in *.out; do
mv $filename ${filename//$dir.out}
done
cd ..
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a free coding service, but it's simple enough to not make it worth arguing about...

Assuming this file structure:

```
Ion_0001/
Ion_0001/light.out
Ion_0002/
Ion_0002/light.out
...
```

Run this code in a script or just at the command line:

```
for i in Ion_0*
do
    mv "${i}/light.out" "${i}/${i}.out"
done
```

Resulting in this structure:

```
Ion_0001/
Ion_0001/Ion_0001.out
Ion_0002/
Ion_0002/Ion_0002.out
...
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes Peter thank you for your help.  I thought it was simple enough too I didn't mean to offend anybody I am just new to this

Answer (score 2):

```
for dir in Ion*/; do 
    mv "${dir}light.out" "${dir}${dir%/}.out"
done
```

The trailing slash in the `Ion*/` pattern limits the results to directories only, but the slash will be present in the variable's value.